# Update certain CKAN dataset metadata

Tags: python, dataset, metadata, ckan

I want to a certain value in a CKAN dataset metadata using CKAN API. I tried using *http://my-ckan-url/api/action/package_update* in a python request but I received an error that the url does not exist. Please any help on how update a CKAN dataset metadata through API will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the documentation here
https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/#ckan.logic.action.update.package_update

The actual URL will be

https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_update with the POST request followed in above documentation.

use your domain name instead of https://demo.ckan.org.

Your address will be http://my-ckan-url/api/3/action/package_update